# Python - name output file to include part of input file name

Tags: python, numpy, path, filenames, python-2.6

I am using python 2.6

I am inputting `n` number of files and using loops to process the data in the files and outputting that information to a single output file.

The input files are named `inputfile_date_time.h5` where each date/time is different for each input file.

I am looking to name the output file `outputfile_firstdate_firsttime_lastdate_lasttime.pkt` - where `firstdate_firsttime` is the date and time of the input file with the first time (aka part of the name of the input file that comes first in the sequence of n files) and where `lastdate_lasttime` is the date and time of the input file with the last time (aka part of the name of the input file that comes last in the sequence of `n` files)

My code is currently set up as follows:

```
import os
from glob import glob
from os.path import basename
import numpy
import hdf5
#set location/directory of input files
inputdir = "/Location of directory that contains files"

#create output file
outputfilename = 'outputfilename'
outputfile = "/Location to put output file/"+basename(outputfilename)[:-4]+".pkt"
ofile = open(outputfile, 'wb')

for path, dirs, files in os.walk(inputdir):
    files_list = glob(os.path.join(inputdir, '*.h5'))
    for file in files_list:
        f = h5py.File(os.path.join(files_list,file), 'r')
        f.close()
    #for loop performing the necessary task to the information in the files
    #print that the output file was written
    print "Wrote " + outputfile
#close output file
ofile.close()
```

This code creates an output file called `outputfile.pkt`

How can I adjust this code to make the changes I previously stated?

Comment: You can use the `re` module and (optionally) `time.strptime` to parse the dates in the input filenames. Once you have the output file name, you may open it for writing directly, or rename it after you have written it to `outputfile.pkt`.

Comment: does the time have to be in a specific format to do it that way? Also how would i make sure I was getting the first and last time with this method. Really I just need to take chunks of the file name and make it the new output file name.

Comment: can you provide some sample filenames?

Comment: Data_d20140526_t2359590_Data.h5 is an example of what an input file would look like. Data_d20140526_t2359590_d20140527_t0019590.pkt is what the output file should look like where d20140526_t2359590 is the date and time contained in the file name of the first-timed input file and d20140527_t0019590 is the date and time contained in the last-timed input file name

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`time.strptime` can parse any time format you want, `time.strftime` can generate any time format you want. You should read (and possibly parse) all of them, and use `min(...)` and `max(...)` to get the smallest and the largest.

For example, if the filenames look like `foo2014-06-16bar.txt` and `hello2014-06-17world`, then here is how to parse them:

```
import re
files = ['foo2014-06-16bar.txt', 'hello2014-06-17world'
dates = [re.search(r'(?:19|20)\d{2}-\d{2}-\d{2}', f).group() for f in files]
print min(dates)  #: 2014-06-16
print max(dates)  #: 2014-06-17
```

Here is how to build `files` using `os.walk`:

```
import os
inputdir = "/Location of directory that contains files"
files = []
for dirpath, dirnames, filenames in os.walk(inputdir):
  for filename in filenames:
    if filename.endswith('.h5'):
      pathname = os.path.join(dirpath, filename)
      files.append(pathname)
print files
```

Comment: there are n number of files so I cannot write them out like that. I need a way to loop through the file names and pull out the earliest timed filename and the latest timed file name and extract the time from the file name

Comment: What's wrong with building the `files` list of `n` files first, and only then doing what you do in the question? Once you have the `files` list, you can iterate over it, you don't have to scan the filesystem again.

Comment: i've tried os.listdir but it doesnt work. I cannot type out the name of 145 files. This code needs to be able to iterate over any directory of files i give it, not just the specific files i'm looking at now

Comment: os.listdir and os.walk both do work in general. If they don't work for you, and you can't fix it alone, then please ask another question of StackOverflow.

Comment: We are obviously misunderstanding each other. I asked this question to get help for just that. The point is I need help formatting a loop that will allow me to use code like this. My code cannot be specific for certain files. I need to be able to run it for ANY directory i choose.

Comment: What's wrong with calling os.listdir or os.walk on any directory of your choice, and building the `files` list based on the output of that? This is standard practice in Python to list files. If it doesn't work for you, than something is wrong with your code. If you can't fix it, ask another question e.g. *How do I fix this code for listing files a directory in Python?*.

Comment: I've extended my answer on how to use `os.walk`.

Comment: thank you! I ended up figuring it out. my code looks similar to what you have above

Comment: Is there anything left unanswered? If not, please accept my answer.